# Help understanding product of topologies (basic question)

Tags: general-topology

I need some help understanding the product of two topologies. Could you please check if my examples are correct? My notes start with a "tentative definition", improve it to the box topology, and then show the Tychonoff product topology.

The first, tentative definition takes that $(X_1, \mathcal{T}_1) \times (X_2, \mathcal{T}_2) = (X_1 \times X_2, \mathcal{T}_3)$, where $\mathcal{T}_3=\{U_1 \times U_2 \mid U_1 \subset X_1$ and $U_2 \subset X_2$ are open$\}$. My example: let $(X_1, \mathcal{T}_1)$ be the usual topology and $(X_2, \mathcal{T}_2)$ be the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then an example of $U_1$ would be the interval $(0,1)$ and an example of $U_2$ would be $\{1,2,3\}$. So their "product" (it's a tentative definition) would be $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{T}_3)$ and the only open sets in $\mathcal{T}_3$ would be pairs like $(x,y)$ where $x \in (0,1)$ (i.e. the open interval between 0 and 1) and $y \in \{1,2,3\}$, correct?  So $\mathcal{T}_3=\{(0.01,1), (0.02,1), (0.5,2), (0.9,2), (0.5,3), (0.9,3), \cdots\}$ (these are pairs, not intervals).

We then go to the box topology in which  $(X_1, \mathcal{T}_1) \times (X_2, \mathcal{T}_2) =(X_1 \times X_2, \mathcal{T}_4)$ such that $\mathcal{T}_4$ is the collection of all subsets $X_1 \times X_2$ that are unions of elements of $\mathcal{T}_3$. In my example this would be $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{T}_4)$ and examples of open sets would be $\{(0.01,1), (0.02,1), (0.9,3)\}, \{(0.5,2), (0.02,1)\}, \{(0.5,3)\}, \{(0.01,1), (0.02,1), (0.5,2), (0.9,2), (0.5,3), (0.9,3)\}$, right?

Now we get to the Tychonoff product topology. I guess in my example the product would be $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{T}_5)$ and the open sets are pairs (because there are two topologies) with the format $\{(x,y)\}$ where $x \in \mathcal{T}_1$ and $y \in \mathcal{T}_2$... but then I don't quite see a difference with the 1st ("tentative") definition.

Many thanks!

Comment: For finitely many topological spaces, the product and box topologies are the same.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thanks for the comment, but is my example of box topology correct?

Comment: Both examples are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $(X_1, \mathcal{T}_1)$ as you say, so $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology and $(X_2, \mathcal{T}_2)$ the set $\Bbb R$ in the discrete topology, then first of all $\mathcal{T}_3 = \{U_1 \times U_2 \mid U_1 \in \mathcal{T}_1; U_2 \in \mathcal{T}_2\}$ is **not** a topology on $X_1 \times X_2$ at all. What it *is* is the standard **base** for a topology on $X_1 \times X_2$ which is called the product topology and the box topology (they're the same here because we have a **finite** product).

That it's not a topology is because it's not closed under arbitrary, or even finite unions. E.g. $(0,1) \times \{1\}$ is in $\mathcal{T}_3$ as $(0,1)$ is standard-open and all subsets, including $\{1\}$ are discrete-open. The same holds for $(2,3) \times \{2\}$. But their union in $X_1 \times X_2$ is **not** of the form $A \times B$ for any $A,B$ so not in $\mathcal{T}_3$ as well.

As said, is *is* a base for a topology so taking all unions we get the product=box topology. It contains exactly such sets as described before e.g. $I \times B$ where $I$ is some open interval or segment of  $\\Bbb R$ and $B$ can be any subset of $\Bbb R$ whatsoever. So way more than you could hope to naively enumerate but we can easily check if a set is in the base or not and that's all that matters. **Your** set description of $\mathcal{T}_3$ consist of individual points in the product and **not** of a set of subsets, which is what it actuallly is. Mind your types!

Answer (score 0):

The intuition behind product (Tychonoff) topology is that you want the coarsest topology where projections are continuous. For finite products these are the same.

$\mathcal T_3$ is not a topology, but a *basis* for a Box topology. Also, $\mathcal T_5$ doesn't make any sense. Please don't write small $x \in \mathcal T$, because $x$ is a *point*, not an *open set*. Write open sets with large capital letters $A\in\mathcal T$.

Comment: Thanks, but are my examples of open sets for $\mathcal{T}_3$ and $\mathcal{T}_4$ correct?

Comment: No, because e.g. $\{0.01\}$ is not an open set (it is closed) if what you mean by $(0.01, 1)$ is in fact $\{0.01\}\times\{1\}$.

An example of open set is e.g. $(0, 1)\times\{1\}$

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm so confused. I do understand that $\{0.01\}$ is not open in the usual topology and that the interval $(0,1)$ is open. So let $U_1 = (0,1)$, and let $U_2=\{1,2,3\}$ (open in the discrete topology).
So, what's $U_1 \times U_2$?